# SAT-based collision resolution in case of edge-to-edge collision

Tags: collision-detection, separating-axis-theorem

I am trying to implement a SAT-based collision detection and collision resolution system.

Collision detection seems to be working correctly, but collision resolution behaves weirdly when there is edge-to-edge collision involved.
There is a visualization of the case I am testing:
[image]

It detects collision correctly, but it doesn't yield correct MTV.
Correct MTV should be (-1, 0, 0) (pushing the left box to the left, in direction opposite to it's velocity), multiplied by an overlap of 0.01.

However, my implementation detects a smaller overlap of 0.00866 on separating axis (-0.866025, 0, 0.5) (which is a cross product of two edges, as opposed to (-1, 0, 0), which is a face normal). I guess this is expected, because this axis has a smaller x component; however, it resolves collision incorrectly, causing the left box to "climb up".

Here is the code. Objects are stored as hexahedrons, with 6 faces that have 4 points each, so it's accessed as hexahedron_ptr->f[i].p[j]:

```
static vec2f hexahedron_project_on_axis(const hexahedron* h1, vec3f axis)
{
    float min = vec3_dot(axis, h1->f[0].p[0]), max = min;
    for(size_t _p = 1; _p < 4; ++_p){
        float proj = vec3_dot(axis, h1->f[0].p[_p]);
        if(proj < min) min = proj;
        else if(proj > max) max = proj;
    }
    for(size_t _f = 1; _f < 6; ++_f){
        for(size_t _p = 0; _p < 4; ++_p){
            float proj = vec3_dot(axis, h1->f[_f].p[_p]);
            if(proj < min) min = proj;
            else if(proj > max) max = proj;
        }
    }
    return (vec2f){min, max};
}
static int do_proj_overlap(vec2f proj1, vec2f proj2)
{
    return proj1.y >= proj2.x || proj1.x <= proj2.y;
}
static float get_proj_overlap(vec2f proj1, vec2f proj2)
{
    return (proj1.y >= proj2.x) ? (proj1.y - proj2.x)
        : (proj2.y - proj1.x); /*proj1.x <= proj2.y*/
}
static size_t hexahedron_get_separating_axes(const hexahedron* h1, const hexahedron* h2, vec3f* axis_arr)
{
    size_t arr_i = 0;
    // get normals to h1 and h2 faces
    for(size_t _f = 0; _f < 6; ++_f){
        vec3f edge1 = vec3_sub(h1->f[_f].p[1], h1->f[_f].p[0]);
        vec3f edge2 = vec3_sub(h1->f[_f].p[2], h1->f[_f].p[1]);
        vec3f norm = vec3_norm(vec3_cross(edge1, edge2));
        int insert = 1;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < arr_i; ++i)
            if(vec3_eq(axis_arr[i], norm))
            { insert = 0; break; }
        if(insert)
            axis_arr[arr_i++] = norm;

        edge1 = vec3_sub(h2->f[_f].p[1], h2->f[_f].p[0]);
        edge2 = vec3_sub(h2->f[_f].p[2], h2->f[_f].p[1]);
        norm = vec3_norm(vec3_cross(edge1, edge2));
        insert = 1;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < arr_i; ++i)
            if(vec3_eq(axis_arr[i], norm))
            { insert = 0; break; }
        if(insert)
            axis_arr[arr_i++] = norm;
    }
    // get all edge-to-edge cases (i.e. cross-products of edges)
    for(size_t _f = 0; _f < 6; ++_f){
        for(size_t _p = 0; _p < 4; ++_p){
            for(size_t _f2 = 0; _f2 < 6; ++_f2){
                for(size_t _p2 = 0; _p2 < 4; ++_p2){
                    vec3f e1 = h1->f[_f].p[_p], e2 = h1->f[_f].p[_p == 3 ? 0 : _p + 1],
                    e3 = h2->f[_f2].p[_p2], e4 = h2->f[_f2].p[_p2 == 3 ? 0 : _p2 + 1];
                    vec3f edge1 = vec3_sub(e1, e2), edge2 = vec3_sub(e3, e4);
                    vec3f edge = vec3_cross(edge1, edge2);
                    vec3f norm = vec3_norm(edge);
                    if(!isnan(norm.x) && !isnan(norm.y) && !isnan(norm.z)){
                        int insert = 1;
                        for(size_t i = 0; i < arr_i; ++i)
                            if(vec3_eq(axis_arr[i], norm))
                            { insert = 0; break; }
                        if(insert)
                            axis_arr[arr_i++] = norm;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr_i;
}

int hexahedron_check_collision(const hexahedron* h1, const hexahedron* h2, vec3f* resol)
{
    vec3f axes[6 + 6 + 256];
    if(!hexahedron_check_projection_collision(h1, h2))
        return 0;
    size_t axes_ln = hexahedron_get_separating_axes(h1, h2, axes);
    float overlap = INFINITY;
    vec3f resolution;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < axes_ln; ++i){
        vec3f axis = axes[i];
        if(vec3_ln(axis) == 0)
            continue;
        vec2f proj1 = hexahedron_project_on_axis(h1, axis),
              proj2 = hexahedron_project_on_axis(h2, axis);
        if(do_proj_overlap(proj1, proj2)){
            float o = get_proj_overlap(proj1, proj2);
            if(o < overlap){
                overlap = o;
                resolution = axis;
            }
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
    resolution = vec3_smul(resolution, overlap);
    *resol = resolution;
    return 1;
}
```

My only idea of how to combat this is to use cross products of edges only to check for collisions, and exclude them from MTV calculation. But I am not sure if this is a correct approach.